# HTML, Markdown or Textile support  in LinkedIn discussion groups

Tags: linkedin, forums, markdown, latex

Does LinkedIn support HTML, [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) or [Textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29) in their discussion groups?

I wrote a long comment in a discussion group on LinkedIn that would have been much easier to read if I could give it some structure like we can here or in [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) comments.

I could just try standard HTML, Markdown and Textile in the LinkedIn posts, but that would basically be spamming.

Answer (score 4):

LinkedIn does not support any of these tools "out of the box".

I created a new private LinkedIn group in which I could make test posts all day long without bothering anyone. HTML, Markdown and Textile all just rendered as plain text with gobbledegook. Some examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[*n.b.: I am new to Textile, so that formatting may be incorrect. Even if so I'd bet you a dollar that correctly written Textile wouldn't work in a LinkedIn discussion.*]

I'll poke around and see if there are any browser extensions or something that will allow this sort of thing. Stay tuned.